# entity cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

My entity Person is generated by EF. I'm trying to show the firstname in a autocomplete textbox when you search for a specific character, just like a facebook search. When I try to run i get the error-message:

```
The entity or complex type 'Dejtingsajt3.Repositories.Person' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
```

This is my script-code from the .html-page:

```
<script>
    $("#searchInput").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetSearchValue", "Home")',
                dataType: "json",
                data: { search: $("#searchInput").val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.FirstName, value: item.FirstName };
                    }));
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is my method from the controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private DataContext dataContext = new DataContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetSearchValue(string search)
    {
        List<Person> allSearch = dataContext.User.Where(n => n.FirstName
        .Contains(search)).Select(x => new Person
        {
            FirstName = x.FirstName

        }).ToList();

        return new JsonResult {Data=allSearch, JsonRequestBehavior =
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}
```

And this is my person-entity:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        FriendRequestReceive = new HashSet<FriendRequest>();
        FriendRequestSend = new HashSet<FriendRequest>();
        MessageRecieve = new HashSet<Message>();
        MessageSend = new HashSet<Message>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A first name is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A last name is required.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A social number is required.")]
    public string SocialNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A gender is required.")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A city is required.")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email.")]
    public string Mail { get; set; }

    public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }

    public string PresentationText { get; set; }

    public string Preference { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A username is required.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "A password is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FriendRequest> FriendRequestReceive { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FriendRequest> FriendRequestSend { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> MessageRecieve { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> MessageSend { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; internal set; }
    public string ContentType { get; internal set; }
    public byte[] File { get; internal set; }
}
```

I have searched for a solution and tried some different approaches but without any luck.

Comment: You can't create a `Person` in an EF query, you must retrieve it from the database. Leave off the `Select`, assuming the type of a `User` object is `Person`.

Comment: @NetMage 
Haha it worked, thank you!!

Comment: Converted to answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a `Person`, you must retrieve from the database. Assuming the object type of `User` is `Person`, just leave off the `Select`:

```
var allSearch = dataContext.User
                    .Where(n => n.FirstName.Contains(search))
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the next part of code:

```
List<Person> allSearch = dataContext
    .User
    .Where(n => n.FirstName.Contains(search))
    .Select(x => new Person { FirstName = x.FirstName })
    .ToList();
```

If you trying to make project onto a mapped entity, what you basically do is partially load an entity, which is not a valid state. It's the reason why You can't project your query onto a mapped entity. You can, however, use an DTO for that:

```
// DTO class for projection
public class PersonDTO
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

// correct query
List<PersonDTO> allSearch = dataContext
    .User
    .Where(n => n.FirstName.Contains(search))
    .Select(x => new PersonDTO { FirstName = x.FirstName })
    .ToList();
```

You have 2 other options too. First, you can map the query into anonymous type:

```
var allSearch = dataContext
    .User
    .Where(n => n.FirstName.Contains(search))
    .Select(x => new { FirstName = x.FirstName })
    .ToList();
```

Also, you can use `Person` class (if you need all Person's fields) but remove projection from your query:

```
List<Person> allSearch = dataContext
    .User
    .Where(n => n.FirstName.Contains(search))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi man, 

I tried it, but it says that I can not convert PersonDTO into Person, since my list is of Person. :-/

Comment: @user7388204 just change your local variable type to the `List<PersonDTO>`. I updated my answer